# Accessing navigation property in Linq returns - "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object"

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am not sure if this is a legitimate bug or am I not seeing something obvious. I'm using EF Core preview 8. This is my code:

```
var customers = dbContext.Customers

                .Include(c => c.Addresses)
                .Include(c => c.Contacts)
                .Where(c => c.TenantId == tenant.Id);

if (!customerSearchCriteria.AccountSurname.IsEmpty())
            {
                customers = customers.Where(c => c.Contacts.Any(a =>
                    a.Surname.RemoveWhitespace().NullSafeToLower()
                        .Contains(customerSearchCriteria.AccountSurname.RemoveWhitespace().NullSafeToLower())));
            }

return customers.Skip(customerSearchCriteria.start).Take(customerSearchCriteria.length).ToList();
```

If I remove the conditional in the middle completely, the query works fine. As soon as I touch the Contacts or Addresses properties, it will return the above exception. Any clues?

I have done some research and found a couple of links on github treating about a similar issue but not sure if that is the same case:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/16719

Comment: Once you decided to use preview (beta) software, make sure you use the latest preview (9 at this time, or even daily builds) until they release - many things don't work in previews and are fixed/updated in the later builds.

Comment: But keep in mind that custom methods like `RemoveWhitespace()` or `NullSafeToLower()` which require client evaluation won't be supported - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client. So you have to find translatable methods, or explicitly switch to LINQ to Objects. Which will kill your paging code performance. I would suggest using `Trim` and `ToLower` instead - they translate to SQL and also naturally deal with `NULL`s.